# can't see iSCSI with lsblk

Tags: iscsi

I've configured a freeNas with iSCSI and two nodes connecting to that device. Everithing it's ok but after reboot I can't see with lsblk:

```
lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   35G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   34G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 30,5G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0  3,5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0            11:0    1  4,2G  0 rom

iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.1.171
192.168.1.171:3260,1 iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:controlm

[root@nodo2 ~]# iscsiadm -m session -P 3 | grep 'Target\|disk'
Target: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:controlm (non-flash)
                Target Reset Timeout: 30
                        Attached scsi disk sdb          State: running
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have discovered the target. It should be connected (login) as the next step.

```
iscsiadm -m node -l -T iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:controlm
```

Check the connected targets:

```
iscsiadm -m session
```

I have the following saved in my bookmarks. https://gist.github.com/albertomolina/6c621aee3f80c5e7baf3c111df670cf0

Comment: I have session connected, but I can't see it: [root@nodo2 ~]# iscsiadm -m session
tcp: [2] 192.168.1.171:3260,1 iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:controlm (non-flash)

Comment: This output shows that you have session connected. Do you see the block device if your run lsblk?

Comment: I can't see it: lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   35G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   34G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 30,5G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0  3,5G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0            11:0    1  4,2G  0 rom

Comment: I missed the part about 2 nodes. Do you have LVM configured or some kind of cluster file system? 
You can try running partprobe on this node. If you are using clustered LVM, try pvscan --cache